# Unity Editor Popup bar error

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I've created a custom editor pop up bar. However the selection I pick keeps resetting each time I select a different game object.

Can someone please take a look over my code to see where it keeps getting reset and how I can stop this from happening? The data I input stays there, it's more a convenience thing that I want option I select to stay open when I come back to the editor window.

```
string[] analytic_Options = {"None", "Button Press"};
private int analytic_Index = 0;

public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
     GUILayout.BeginVertical();
     GUILayout.Space(10); 

     analytic_Index = EditorGUILayout.Popup(analytic_Index, analytic_Options);

     UpdateEditorGUI();

     GUILayout.Space(10);

     GUILayout.EndVertical();
}


void UpdateEditorGUI()
{

  switch(analytic_Index)
  {

    case 0:         // No analytics selected
      break;

    case 1:         // Button analytic info
     string name_HolderString = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Event Category", target_Object.button_NameString);

     if(target_Object.button_NameString != name_HolderString)
     {

         button_EventNameString = name_HolderString;
         target_Object.button_NameString = name_HolderString;

     }

     break;



  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However the selection I pick keeps resetting each time I select a
>   different game object.

I guess you are referring to `analytic_Index`. Everytime your windows (or inspector) is closed, all non serialized properties will be lost. [Here](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2012/10/25/unity-serialization/) an exhaustive description of how serialization works in `Unity`.

In a few words, for what concern your specific case. Every member variable of `Editor` class (or `EditorWindow`) won't be serialized, so it will be lost when the window is closed (or switching to play mode). Generally the [SerializedProperties](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html) belong to a particular asset (`MonoBehavior`, `ScriptableObject`,..), so you can put such a value on the particular asset you are visualizing through your `EditorWindow` (or `Editor`).

Comment: Informative answer, so I've upvoted, but it turns out I didn't set my index value as a static value. I did that and it's fixed.

Comment: Yes, of course a static works, at least until you close the editor :) . It probably depends on what you are doing but in the general case it's probably not the best way to go.